# Header h1 always shows blue color

Tags: css

I have an external css file, all other parts are working correctly except for the header color. For some reason it stays with blue color.

```
<h1><a href="{% url 'home' %}">My Header</a></h1>
```

```
header {
    padding: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

header h1, header h1:visited {
    padding: 20px 0 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: 'Black Ops One', cursive;
}
```

I did the following checks:

1. the css is linking to the html file properly, other styles from this css file are working as expected.
2. the code block contains the only styles for h1 in my css file, there is no overwriting situation before or after it.
3. there is no inline styles in my html files. All the styles are in this external css file.
4. I tried to adjust the h1 as well as its visited/active/hover and changed the colors to see if there's any updates, but no, my header is always blue.

Originally I thought it might be caused by that I've clicked the link of the header so it turned blue. My navigation bar first behaved the same, after adjusting, the navigation bar is showing the color it supposed to show. Did the same adjustment for header but the header insists being blue. So at this point I'm not sure where the problem is and how to fix it. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Please add a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem

Comment: U needed to add your HTML because it's likely there has a <a> wrap within that header. In that case, then should set `a {color:#000}` or add `!important` to your header color

Comment: Thank you. I've updated my code and you are very right about the a tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a link within your `<h1>`, you have to set color for it separately:

`header h1 a {color:#000}`

Quick example:

```css
header h1 {color:#000}

header#c h1 a {color:#000}
```

```html
<header>
<h1>no link</h1>
<h1><a href="#">link</a></h1>
</header>

<header id="c">
<h1><a href="#">colored link</a></h1>
</header>
```

Also please note that
`:visited` is valid for links only,
`:active` is valid for links, form elements and elements with `tabindex`.
That's why they do not work on `h1`.

Comment: Good answer, although you generally shouldn't make an answer assuming something about their code, thats on op.

Comment: @Laif, OP wrote `it might be caused by that I've clicked the link of the header`. So it was not an assumption. =))

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a very accurate prediction. And I should've post my html code with css. Oh and thank you for the side note, I started learning front-end development and clearly I should read books more carefully. :D

Comment: @Madmint, happy to help!